# IntelliSense is not working for selenium (with Python3) in visual code

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Please find the configuration below,

Python      : 3.6 
Selenium    : 3.141.0 
path        : ..\Python\PY36\Lib\site-packages\selenium 
Visual Code : 1.33.1

Problem     : The IntelliSense is not working for selenium(Python3) in visual code.

Comment: Have you googled "Intellisense not working python visual code" or something similar and looked at the results and tried some of the fixes? My guess is that you aren't the first person to have this issue and the answer already exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved, I was installed the the selenium inside a virtual environment, instead of that, selenium installed outside the venv. now the Intellisense for Selenium is working as expected.